# CoreVideo / IOSurface: unknown pixel format

Tags: ios, core-video, iosurface

I'm trying to capture an IOSurface using both `CVPixelBufferCreateWithIOSurface` and by reading pixels from `IOSurfaceGetBaseAddressOfPlane`.

However, on newer devices (iPhone XS), I get an unknown pixel format `&wq2` (again, using both `IOSurfaceGetPixelFormat` and `CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType`).

`CVPixelFormatDescriptionCreateWithPixelFormatType` returns the following:

```
@"{\n    BitsPerComponent = 10;\n    ComponentRange = FullRange;\n    ContainsAlpha = 1;\n    ContainsGrayscale = 0;\n    ContainsRGB = 1;\n    ContainsYCbCr = 0;\n    PixelFormat = 645346401;\n    Planes =     (\n                {\n            BitsPerBlock = 64;\n            CompressionType = 2;\n            TileHeight = 16;\n            TileWidth = 16;\n        }\n    );\n}"
```

My code works perfectly on older devices (where it returns `BGRA` as the pixel format), but breaks down on what I assume are newer devices. How can I unmarshal the pixels from this undocumented format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a bad habit of answering my own questions.

To convert this `IOSurface` to say an `IOSurface` with a known pixel type, an `IOAccelerator` should be used.

```
    CFMutableDictionary dict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);;
    char pixelFormat[4] = {'A', 'R', 'G', 'B'};

    CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfaceBytesPerRow, CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &bytesPerRow));
    CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfaceBytesPerElement, CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &bytesPerElement));
    CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfaceWidth, CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &width));
    CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfaceHeight, CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &height));
    CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfacePixelFormat, CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, pixelFormat));
    CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kIOSurfaceAllocSize, CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &bufferSize));
    IOSurfaceRef surface = IOSurfaceCreate(dict);

    auto const didCreateAccelerator = IOSurfaceAcceleratorCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &accelerator);
```